# Expect for value with a flag inside

Tags: tcl, expect

That's a send-expect sequence automation:

```
proc se {cmd ex} {
    send $cmd\r
    expect {
        $ex {return}
        "timeout" {send_user "ops"; exit 0} }
}
```

Generally I call proc *se* with simple args:

```
se "show run" "#"
```

But sometimes I have to expect for regular expression:

```
se "show int" "-re interface.{4}"
```

And get the error:

```
bad flag "-re interface.{4}" must be -glob, -regexp, -exact ...
```

How to force Expect to separate flag and value in argumet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tcl8.5 or above, you can argument expansion operator `{*}`. Else, go ahead with `eval`

**Tcl8.5 or above**

```
proc se {cmd ex} {
    send $cmd\r
    expect \
        timeout {send_user "ops";exit 0} \
        {*}$ex {puts "matched pattern"}
}
```

**Less than Tcl8.5**

```
proc se {cmd ex} {
    send $cmd\r
    eval expect \
       timeout {{send_user "ops";exit 0}} \
       $ex {{puts "Matched pattern"}}
}
```

Comment: I have 8.5, tried both variants. Theoretically 1st can help, but "expect" still get {*}"-re expression" as the flag.

Comment: I have tested both and found to be working. I doubt you might be missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own wish mindless and prefered to operate $ex as list. If $ex started with "-", throw first element of $ex to option of expect, otherwise $ex is body.